# Print all substrings, no matter how many there are

Tags: python, list, printing

So i have this code where i'm creating a list with substrings:
'''

```
string = "|01|12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|"

x = string.count("|")

if string.count('|') == 3:

    subst = string.strip('|').split('|')

    print(substr)

else:

    substr = string.strip('|').split('|')

    print(substr)
```

'''

Outcome:

'''

```
['01', '12345', 'TEXT1', 'TEXT2']
```

'''

However, i want to print all the substrings that the outcome is this:

'''

```
[LAS|01|G12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|<CR>|]
```

'''

I know i can just do:

'''

```
print("[LAS|" + substr[0] + "|G" + substr[1] + "|" + substr[2] + "|" + substr[3] + "|<CR>|]")
```

'''

But this is hardcoded, what if my the string that i get makes way more substrings? I do not want to use allot of if statements, if the count of ('|') == 4, == 5, == 6 etc.

How do i make sure that what i print contains all the substrings. And has a pipe symbol (|) in between every substring.

Thanks,

Comment: Look at `string.split("|")` for making the substrings.

Comment: Use `str.strip.split`: `s.strip("|").split("|")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split` to make the substrings and `str.strip` to remove the potential leading and trailing pipes that will make you have empty substrings:

```py
string = "01|12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|TEXT3|"

if string.count('|') == 3:
    # Do something
else:
    substrings = string.strip('|').split('|')
    # Do something
```

Comment: Nice use of strip, this should be preferred to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the empty string before a 1st character vbar or the empty string after a final character vbar, I would try:

```
string = "01|12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|TEXT3|"
x = string.split("|")
if x[0] == "":
    x = x[1:]
if x[-1] == "":
    x = x[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of a string.

```py
string = "01|12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|TEXT3|"

substring = filter(lambda x: x =! '', string.split('|'))
print(substring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code

```
chain = "|01|12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|Text3|"

result = chain.strip('|').split('|')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
split_string = string.split("|")
```

If the variable string is:

```
 "aa|bb|cc|dd"
```

the variable split_string will be:

```
 ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]
```

Then, every index of the list "split_string" will be one of the substrings that you want.